# como puedo quitar las comillas de un string en la salida de un archivo en haskell

Tags: haskell

```
writeFile "CRITICOS.txt" (show ([head nodocritico]))
```

pero en el archivo me lo muestra así `["C"]` y quiero ponerlo así `[C]` como podría quitar las dobles comillas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La instancia `show` para `[a]` es basado en la definicion de `show` para `a` y `Show String` siempre pone dobles comillas alrededor del `String`.

Puedes omitir las dobles comillas escribiendo su propria version de la funcion:

```
import Data.List

myShow :: [String] -> String
myShow strs = concat [ "[", intercalate "," strs, "]" ]
```

Puedes tambien reutilizar la instancia `Show [a]` usando un `newtype` wrapper para cambiar la instancia que ghc selecciona:

```
newtype NoDoblesComillas = NDC { getString :: String }

instance Show NoDoblesComillas where
  show = getString -- usando el string directamente

myShow :: [String] -> String
myShow = show . fmap NDC
```